# is it possible to install CDH in 32 bit Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: hadoop, ubuntu-12.04, 32-bit, cloudera

I am trying to install CDH4 in Ubuntu 12.04. My PC is 32 bit compatible.

So can i get a 32 bit CDH4 or CDH3 to install in pseudo distributed mode.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can install cloudera on 32 bit system as well see this

http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CDH4/4.2.0/CDH4-Installation-Guide/cdh4ig_topic_4_4.html